# JavaScript bind element events as soon as element is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want to make things happen with DOM elements as soon as they are loaded (found nothing with search on this site or Google, but it is hard to explain this with few words). For example, when a big page is loading I want to hide/add `onlick` events/etc. to elements as soon as they appear on user's screen not on `$(document).ready()`. I wrote a simple class (just for training, closures are new for me so there may be lots of errors) that does what I want but I want to use something better for commercial useb(on the site I'm helping to develop). Here is my source code:

```
function MY_loader() {
    function container() {
        this.add_event = function(new_event,obj_selector,settings) {
            if(typeof(settings)!='object') {
                settings={};
            }
            if(typeof(settings.event_id)!='string') {
                settings.event_id=gen_new_event_id();
            }
            settings=$.extend({},default_settings,settings);
            settings.obj_selector=obj_selector;
            settings.event=new_event;
            events[settings.event_id]=settings;
        }

        this.execute_events = function(if_force) {
            if(typeof(if_force)=='undefined') {
                if_force=false;
            }
            if(html_is_loaded&&!if_force) {
                return;
            }
            var temp_obj;
            for(var event_name in events) {
                temp_obj=$(events[event_name].obj_selector);
                if(temp_obj.length || (html_is_loaded && events[event_name].if_force)) {
                    temp_obj.each(function() {
                        if(events[event_name].expect_multiple) {
                            if($(this).data('my_loader_'+events[event_name].event_id+'_executed')) {
                                
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        if(events[event_name].event_type!='func') {
                            $(this).bind(events[event_name].event_type+'.'+events[event_name].event_id,events[event_name].event);
                        }
                        else {
                            events[event_name].event($(this));
                        }
                        if(events[event_name].expect_multiple) {
                            alert('here');
                            $(this).data('my_loader_'+events[event_name].event_id+'_executed',1);
                        }
                    });
                       //alert(events[event_name].obj_selector+' '+events[event_name].event_type);
                    if(!events[event_name].expect_multiple) {
                        delete events[event_name];
                    }
                }
            }
            if(!html_is_loaded) {
               var cur_time=new Date().getTime();
               setTimeout('MY_loader().execute_events();',Math.max(Math.min(tick_time-(cur_time-last_tick_time),tick_time),0,min_tick_diff));
               last_tick_time=cur_time;
            }
        }

        this.html_is_loaded_set=function(if_html_is_loaded) {
            html_is_loaded=if_html_is_loaded?true:false;
        };

        this.html_is_loaded_get=function() {
            return html_is_loaded?true:false;
        };
        
        return this;
    }
    function instance(if_strat) {
        if(typeof(class_is_loaded)=='undefined'||!class_is_loaded) {
            load_class();
        }
        return container(if_strat);
    }

    var load_class=function() {
        this.class_is_loaded=true;
        this.events = {};
        this.allowed_event_id_chars='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
        this.default_settings={
            'event_type':'click',
            'if_force':false,
            'expect_multiple':false
        };
        this.tick_time=500;
        this.min_tick_diff=100;
        this.last_tick_time=0;
        this.html_is_loaded=false;
        MY_loader().execute_events();
        $(document).ready(function(){
            MY_loader().html_is_loaded_set(true);
            MY_loader().execute_events(true);
        });
    }

    var gen_new_event_id=function() {
        for(var new_id=gen_random_id();typeof(events[new_id])!='undefined';new_id=gen_random_id());
        return new_id;
    }

    var gen_random_id=function() {
        var allowed_event_id_chars_size=allowed_event_id_chars.length;
        var new_id='';
        for(var i=0;i<10;i++) {
            new_id+=allowed_event_id_chars[get_random_int(0,allowed_event_id_chars_size-1)];
        }
        return new_id;
    }

    function get_random_int(min, max)
    {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

    return new instance();
}
//Add click event to #some_selector (once and dont check after it)
MY_loader().add_event(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
}, '#some_selector');
//Hide elements as soon as they are loaded.
//We expect multiple elements with this selector, so it will
//check for this elements untill document is loaded, but this function
//will be applied only one time for each element.
MY_loader().add_event(function(obj) {
    obj.hide();
    alert('This should happen before DOM is completely loaded!');
}, '.some_other_selector',{'event_type':'func','expect_multiple':true});
//This alert should be outputted the last
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('Document is fully loaded!');
});
```

UPD: To make this question a little bit more interesting as it seems too specific I must add: most of the browsers start page rendering before it is completely loaded (this seems to be not well-known for some reason), here are a few links:

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_rendering
2. [When do browsers start to render partially transmitted HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203751/when-do-browsers-start-to-render-partially-transmitted-html)
3. http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?t=161099

So, my problem should be more widely known as this incremental page loading adds lots of problems for developer: user can click on non-working buttons before page is loaded, some things that are hidden by JavaScript on load may show and they can be ugly, etc. (this are examples from my problem). Do other developers just ignore this problem? Please, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Are you working with some browser that actually renders the page before the DOM is constructed? I'm unaware of any browsers that do that.

Comment: @kinakuta: Nearly every browser does that: for example firefox(100% tested). Read comments for: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.flush.php, but that is not the only case when it happens (even with gzip enabled).

Comment: You probably already know this but document.ready() isn't the same as body onload. onload waits for all assets (images/css/etc) to be loaded but document.ready() does not. Unless you have a massive DOM structure seems unlikely that the user will be able to select anything before .ready() fires?

Comment: @Steve Claridge: Well, yes, I have a few really massive pages(white/black lists etc.) - I know I should change them but I don't currently have time to do it. I just added output flushing to temporary solve problem, but then this problem appeared. I remember that when I surf The Web I sometimes too see only a part of page first(head and a bit of body) and then the rest of the page loads (I doubt it was ajax), so maby some big sites use something like this too, but maby it is just my imagination(hope not) :)

Comment: What if you have rendered an element that references another that has not yet been rendered? Could lead to broken actions?

Comment: @Steve Claridge: that is solvable problem - finding lowermost referenced node in a function is not that hard. But theoretically yes, it can cause problems )

Comment: @kinakuta: I added a few links to my post that you may find interesting.

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is that you don't want users to see the page before it is final, you can probably get away with doing the DOM modification straightaway, e.g.:

```
<a href="#" id="test">Test</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="enhancePage.js"></script>
```

Because the node in question exists in the DOM before the script is parsed, you can work with it.

Comment: I thought about that too, but I don't want to mix html with javascript - it is much harder to maintaing(complete javascript files are easier to read) and I surely want all of my javascript cached.

Comment: Then just make sure to include the script after all the nodes have been written that the script might care about.

Comment: It will be the same as $(document).ready() as some of the nodes are in the end of the page.