# Loading Icon While Page Loads

Tags: loading

I would like to add in coding to change my "next" button into a "loading" Gif while it loads the next page.  Apologies for the ignorant question but does that code go in the current page with the "next" button or does it go in the page to be loaded ?  Essentially i would like it to display in the current page as the new page to be loaded looks completely different.

So in short, button says "next", they click it, it says "loading" once the new page is complete it must then reroute to that page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apologies , its a webpage using php.

Comment: A bit more context would be useful. What technologies are you using? I somehow assume you are using an async ajax call that returns you the entire web page, or at least the info you put inside. In this case things are not that complicated. Your click listener just updates the _src_ tag of the button and launches the ajax call. When the ajax call returns your object you pass it on to the next page and route to it.

Comment: its a desktop site

Comment: Try to find similar SO questions that might have been resolved already. I found this one for instance, that might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374535/load-page-while-php-is-executing

Comment: Thanks Vlad, much appreciated.  So i'm correcting in saying the ajax call code is placed in the current webpage not in the page to be loaded, the page to be loaded is merely referenced for routing purposes.